How to count the number of power-on events and their durations for diodes based on timestamps?
I'm working on a problem where I need to analyze the power-on events of diodes over time. For simplicity, let's say that my objects are diodes, and the "date" represents the date and time when a particular diode is turned on. I record these timestamps every second. For example, consider the following data:



Object_ID
date




1
2024-07-17T12:00:00


1
2024-07-17T12:00:01


1
2024-07-17T15:00:00


2
2024-07-17T22:00:00


2
2024-07-17T23:00:00


3
2024-07-17T12:00:00


4
2024-07-17T13:00:00



From the first three rows, we can infer that diode 1 was powered on at 12:00:00, stayed on for another second, then was turned off and back on 3 hours later for one second (or less).
What I need to determine is:

How many times each diode was powered on. (For example, diodes 1 and 2 were powered on 2 times, while diodes 3 and 4 were powered on just once.)
The duration of each power-on event for every diode. (For example, for diode 1, it was on for 2 seconds during the first event and 1 second during the second event.)


What had you tried?

@Wonka Just now I've tried grouping by "Object_ID" and then calling original_df["difference"] = grouped_df["date"].diff() - That allows me to count how many values in difference  are different then 1 second (so NaT or bigger than 1 second). I don't know if it is the most effecient way. Still have no good idea how to calculate duration of each event.

You can use a diff and some filtering to only keep the diffs that are below the step:
# ensure datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def duration(s, step='1s'):
    diff = s.diff()    # diff of successive datetime
    m = diff.le(step)  # keep those within step
    # sum deltas, add 1s for each start
    return diff[m].sum()+pd.Timedelta(step)*(~m).sum()

out = (df.groupby('Object_ID', as_index=False)
         .agg(**{'n_events': ('date', lambda x: (~x.diff().le('1s')).sum()),
                 'duration': ('date', duration)
                })
      )

Output:
   Object_ID  n_events        duration
0          1         2 0 days 00:00:03
1          2         2 0 days 00:00:02
2          3         1 0 days 00:00:01
3          4         1 0 days 00:00:01

aggregating events separately
You can use a similar logic, first form the groups based on the diff greater than the step (or another threshold if you prefer). Then group again and aggregate the duration:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

step = pd.Timedelta('1s')

g = df.groupby('Object_ID')['date']

out = (df.assign(duration=g.diff(),
                 event=g.transform(lambda x: x.diff().gt(step).cumsum()))
         .groupby(['Object_ID', 'event'], as_index=False)
         ['duration'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].sum()+step)
      )

Output:
   Object_ID  event        duration
0          1      0 0 days 00:00:02
1          1      1 0 days 00:00:01
2          2      0 0 days 00:00:01
3          2      1 0 days 00:00:01
4          3      0 0 days 00:00:01
5          4      0 0 days 00:00:01


Thank you very much! It is almost exactly what I need. Only difference is that I don't need total duration of each diode but duration of each event. In the end I would want to do things like histogram of event durations - that's why I can't sum them up for every diode.

I see,you can use a similar logic, see update

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    'date': [
        '2024-07-17T12:00:00',
        '2024-07-17T12:00:01',
        '2024-07-17T15:00:00',
        '2024-07-17T22:00:00',
        '2024-07-17T23:00:00',
        '2024-07-17T12:00:00',
        '2024-07-17T13:00:00'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Convert date to timestamps for numerical operations
df['timestamp'] = df['date'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

# Calculate the time difference between consecutive rows
df['time_diff'] = np.diff(df['timestamp'], prepend=df['timestamp'][0])

# Define a minimum gap threshold for a new event (e.g., 1 second)
min_gap = 1
# Identify power-on events: start of a new event if time_diff is more than 1 second or NaT (first entry)
df['new_event'] = (df['time_diff'] > min_gap) | (df.index == 0)  #or (np.arange(len(df)) == 0)

# Assign an event ID to each power-on event
df['event_id'] = np.cumsum(df['new_event'])

'''
   id                date   timestamp  time_diff  new_event  event_id
0   1 2024-07-17 12:00:00  1721217600          0       True         1
1   1 2024-07-17 12:00:01  1721217601          1      False         1
2   1 2024-07-17 15:00:00  1721228400      10799       True         2
3   2 2024-07-17 22:00:00  1721253600      25200       True         3
4   2 2024-07-17 23:00:00  1721257200       3600       True         4
5   3 2024-07-17 12:00:00  1721217600     -39600      False         4
6   4 2024-07-17 13:00:00  1721221200       3600       True         5
'''
# Calculate the duration of each power-on event
event_durations = df.groupby(['id', 'event_id']).agg(
    start_time=('date', 'first'),
    end_time=('date', 'last'),
    duration=('timestamp', lambda x: (x.max() - x.min() + 1))  # Add 1 second to include the start
).reset_index()

# Calculate the number of power-on events for each diode
power_on_counts = df.groupby('id')['event_id'].nunique().reset_index()
power_on_counts.columns = ['id', 'power_on_count']

'''
Power-On Counts:
   id  power_on_count
0   1               2
1   2               2
2   3               1
3   4               1

Event Durations:
   id  event_id          start_time            end_time  duration
0   1         1 2024-07-17 12:00:00 2024-07-17 12:00:01         2
1   1         2 2024-07-17 15:00:00 2024-07-17 15:00:00         1
2   2         3 2024-07-17 22:00:00 2024-07-17 22:00:00         1
3   2         4 2024-07-17 23:00:00 2024-07-17 23:00:00         1
4   3         4 2024-07-17 12:00:00 2024-07-17 12:00:00         1
5   4         5 2024-07-17 13:00:00 2024-07-17 13:00:00         1
'''

